# 2.8: How to enable Eevee on a Macbook pro?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

EDIT: So now I have my answer, 2.8 doesn't work with my OS (10.9.5), but it works with a more recent one like Mojave.

I wonder how to enable Eevee on a Macbook pro. For the moment if I choose Eevee as *Render Engine*, here is the result I get (image below, Rendered mode with no material). I also screenshot my Preferences if it helps. My Macbook Pro is a Retina, 15 pouces, mid-2014, the video card is Intel Iris Pro (GPU type), OS X (version 10.9.5).

Thanks a lot!!!

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the specs of your MBP. There should be some kind of Compute Device showing up. It could be possible that your GPU is not supported. Have you added any kind of materials to your objects yet? - Also, are you in rendered view?

Comment: Hello Michaelh, thanks for your answer, the screenshot is in Rendered mode, the objects have no material, the MBP is a Retina, 15 pouces, mid-2014, the video card is Intel Iris Pro (GPU type), I hope it helps

Comment: I just installed the latest build of 2.8 on my MBP mit 2012 and Eevee works just fine. ("fine" meaning very slowly, but it works). It is odd, that you have only "none" for Cycles Compute Device. There should be more Tabs and AT LEAST your CPU should show up. Are you on Mojave? It looks like something on your System is just not supported, yet. You could check other applications if they show your hardware, just to be sure it's Blender related and not sth. else. Also, always try the latest builds. Amazing Blender Devs keep fixing stuff all the time.

Comment: my OS is 10.9.5, and same problem with the latest version of Blender 2.8. If I switch to Cycles I can choose between Device > CPU or GPU Compute (but I still have a None on the System Preferences). If you have any idea please tell me, I'm also going to ask on devtalk.blender.org, thanks  ;)

Comment: Oh, that's Mavericks. That's really old by now. Hard to tell if that's the issue, but I'd assume that 2.8 is mostly tested on more recent versions of macOS and it could take a while until bugs with the old versions get ironed out. (Certainly not a priority right now, as the focus is on the beta release atm.) You should definitely mention that right at the beginning when you post on devtalk. Hope you can find help there. But I suggest you should consider upgrading your OS at some point.

Comment: Ok that would explain the bug, thanks a lot   ;)

Comment: I've tried Mojave and it works. My problem is that for the moment it will be a bit complicated to switch to Mojave, but I least I know where the problem comes from. Thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not something you have to enable, EEVEE is just here and you have to chose it as your current render engine, just like before.

Go in the properties editor, you'll find a drop-down menu for choosing your render engine at the very top of the render tab :

[image: renderer drop down]

EDIT: As the OP is already in rendered view in EEVEE and without materials, then it looks like a bug.

Comment: Hello Lolock, actually I've already chosen Eevee, the screenshot I show is the result I've got   ;)

Comment: Then you have nothing else to do \o/

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: Me neither, what are you trying to do? Once you've switched your render engine to be EEVEE, that's it, nothing else needed to use EEVEE.

Comment: looks what I've got when I switch to Eevee (screenshot). Don't you think there's a problem?

Comment: Oh yes. Since I don't know what display mode you're using and what are your materials, I can't really tell. If you are in rendered display and that your materials are not supposed to look like this, then it might be a bug. (And to me, it looks like you're rendering some output from a texture coordinates node, maybe check your materials ?).

Comment: This is the Rendered mode with no material

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86054/discussion-between-l0lock-and-moonboots).

Comment: Ok, then it might be a bug.

Comment: Lolock, it works with Mojave, so I guess 10.9.5 is too old. Thanks for your help

Comment: I communicate this topic out here : https://devtalk.blender.org/t/hardware-requirements-for-blender-2-8/3440/7
Wait'n'see.